# MacBook Pro 13" Snow Leopard: WiFi suddenly stopped working

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

I bought my first Mac ten months ago which worked flawlessly until yesterday. Out of the blue, it can no longer connect to my wireless network.

I haven't made any changes to my Mac or to the network; my other machines have full Internet access. I have tried to remove the wireless network and add it again (on my Mac). I've also deleted the entries in the key-chain and restarted my router but nothing helps.

Does anyone recognize this problem (and of course have a solution for it)?

Comment: Does your Macbook connect to 'other' Wifi access points? It happened to me once, I just changed the router and it started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has happened to me before. If your other devices work properly with your current router, you may want to try other troubleshooting tips:

1. Try deleting your WiFi connection and recreating it - it's possible that the config for that particular connection got corrupted
2. As rubayeet suggests, try checking with other WiFi access points to confirm whether your MBP's wifi hardware is working.

Do as much as you can to rule out specific system failures - either hardware or software on your MBP. I strongly recommend the first - I've had to recreate a WiFi connection before. It's also possible that your router is having issues, but that may be less likely since your other machines seem to be connecting fine wirelessly.

If all that fails, it may be time to bring it back to the Apple Store for repair. But trying the other two steps above may fix it for you.

Good luck!

Comment: Thx rubayeet and JW01! When I got back from work today I started my MBP and it connected to my wifi network as it used to do before (except from yesterday). I will not touch anything and pray that this will never happen again. Thanx again for quick answers and help.

Comment: @Ausgar, you're welcome - glad to hear it's working now!

Comment: As a general note, if you run into Wireless issues on Mac, open your terminal and type ifconfig -a. You should see en0 and en1, and possibly others. But the important part is that en0 is your wired adapter and en1 is your wireless. If it doesn't show up your Airport may be turned off.